# Login to a website automatically via Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension for a University website which likes to always make you log in, so one of the features I am trying to implement has to do with logging the user in automatically.

I could at the first load of the webpage automate clicking the login button and filling in the login data, however I want to make it more transparent and login in the background. Having the users username and password is it possible to do a login in the background by calling the same url the site uses and giving the post data? The site uses https, would this cause issues? How would I do this? Any good examples out there of this?

Comment: Can you describe how the login process works? You say "same url [...] and giving the post data", you mean like a POST request?

Comment: @Xan yes it is a post request. To get to the login page you must actually hit login and then wait for login page to load and then put in your login info. I essentially just want to be on the main page (separate from login page) and submit a post request to log the user in automatically.